# I want to clean up my if-else logic

Tags: java, coding-style, if-statement, code-cleanup

This seems inefficient or ugly or for whatever reason, I would like it to be more elegant

```
if (a > b) {
    recurseWith(a);
    recurseWith(b);
else {
    recurseWith(b);
    recurseWith(a);
}
```

In my code a and b are longer, and the parameters to the new function are more bulky, and it just looks lame. Is there a way to clean this up?

The order matters because they work with a global variable and, well, this code just works.

I'm looking for a solution in Java

-Austin

Comment: How about writing a method that returns an ordered list of objects that will be parameters to _recurseWith()_?  Then you could iterate over the list and call _recurseWith()_ on each item.

Answer (score 0):

Will following logic not help here ?

```
if(a<=b) swap(a,b);

recurseWith(a);
recurseWith(b);
```

Comment: this is fine. I'm using ArrayLists, so to swap them might require me to create a swap method, which is more code elsewhere. Good to have in my mental toolkit at least. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

I don't have a good answer, but depending on the grossness/longness of the parameters can hide them in a Runnable so you only have to write them once.  Your decide whether this is "cleaner".  It's going to look worse here, because we're using `a` and `b`.

```
Runnable aRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        recurseWith(a);
    }
}

Runnable bRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        recurseWith(b);
    }
}

if (a > b) {
    aRunnable.run();
    bRunnable.run();
else {
    bRunnable.run();
    aRunnable.run();
}
```

Comment: I like! Never used a Runnable before. Thanks

Comment: That does absolutely no good.  If he simply wants subroutines for a complex "recurseWith" invocation he can write subroutines.  No need for Runnables.

Comment: But how would he pass all of the gross arguments to that subroutine?  He would have to pass them grossly, again.  This lets you use the fact that the variables are in scope when you define the Runnable to your advantage.

Comment: It seems awfully wrong to use a _Runnable_ just to clean up the appearence of code.  Not to mention the fact that the whole point of his task is to do things synchronously (in a specified order).  Using _Runnables_ would completely ignore this requirement!

Comment: @jahroy Hmm, seems like I'm alone in my thinking here.  I see a Runnable as a lightweight object; if the method has 7 or 8 parameters with long names, it might appear as less code and be less error prone to write it this way, as compared to copy-pasting the method invocation into the else block.  Nothing about them makes them run out of order; they aren't run until you explicitly call `run`.  I'll take the downvotes but leave my answer, as I think it has use in a few rare situations.

Comment: I guess if you don't use _Runnable_ the way it was meant to be used (to execute a separate thread of execution) then the order of operation is not necessarily lost.  I think it's a very bad idea to abuse the _Runnable_ interface just to make code more visually attractive.  To quote the API documentation: "_The Runnable interface should be implemented by any class whose instances are intended to be executed by a thread_".

Comment: Also.... Why would you even choose to use _Runnable_ in this example?  Why not just create an interface named _Funky_ with a method named _FunkyRun_?  That would achieve the exact same goal (nothing).  Heck, you could even implement _Comparable_ and abuse that the same way by making the _compareTo_ method perform a bunch of business logic (also a horrible idea).

Comment: @jahroy I chose it out of habit: as a stand-in for other langauge's ability to pass functions as arguments.  One class means that should others integrate with my code, they wont have to import and understand what a FunkRun is.  Callable exists if you want a return value or to throw Exceptions, or (if you're into third party java APIs) GoogleGuava provides http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Function.html and http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Predicate.html and

Comment: It might make sense if you made use of the function aspect of it, but you didn't.  You might, eg, assign runnableA to x and runnableB to y for the greater-than case and vice-versa for less-equal case.  Then you could just invoke x and y in order, with no further ifs.  No help in this toy example, but perhaps useful in a more complex case.  But simply creating the objects does no real good -- just confusion and overhead.